# Can't mv files between directories on vsftpd

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I enabled this in vsftpd.conf

> chroot_local_user=YES
>
> chroot_list_enable=YES
>
> chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
>
> user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf

and here is the user set in vsftpd_user_conf dirctory

ftpupload :

> local_root=/mnt/upload

But /mnt/upload is mounted from another directory

> /mnt/upload on /opt/upload type none (rw,bind)

Here is the list in `/mn/upload`

> rough_images/
>
> shoes-pentland/
>
> vendor-upload/
>
> shooting/

Additional, the `shooting/` directory is mounted from another place

> /mnt/upload/shooting on /mnt/shooting none (rw,bind)

Now here is the problem.

When I use the ftp client to move the files between the directories but failed .Files can moved between any directories except the `shooting` one.

The permission is right . I can move any files between this directories successful by using `su ftpupload`.

It means the vsftpd didn't support the `mount bind`?

---

Here is the vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=000
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=app
xferlog_std_format=NO
log_ftp_protocol=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
ls_recurse_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=***
pasv_min_port=***
port_enable=YES
pasv_address=***
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

and here is the mtab:

```
    /mnt/upload /opt/upload none rw,bind 0 0
    /mnt/upload/shooting /mnt/shooting none rw,bind 0 0
```

all of the permissions under the /mnt/upload are the same:

> drwxrwxrwx * ftpupload app

Comment: I have used vsftd with mount bind before with no issues. Can you verify the permissions are set correctly on ALL of the folders? It sounds like a permission issue

Comment: @NicYoung I doubted it may caused by permission issue at first. But I have the write permission when I ssh on the server with the user.I am sure the permission is right. Did you mount the directory like me ? Not mount only one , but any ?

Comment: Yes I had many folders mounted under my ftp root directory. I would ensure that your user has write permissions to these mounted folders as well.

Comment: @NicYoung yes I login with `ftpupload` username to the server , create new files and move any files between these directories. BTW, I chmod all of the directories with `777` mode.

Comment: Ok can you post your `vsftpd.conf` and `/etc/fstab`? Also if you can post the permissions for all of the directories under ftp root.

Comment: @NicYoung I updated the post. so can you give me any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you chrooting the user into `/mnt/upload`? The problem may be that vsftpd detects `/mnt/upload/shooting` to be outside the chroot, although I would expect the bind mount to make this work. Try disabling the chroot or chrooting the user to `/mnt`.